# Special characters in Kile

Tags: symbols, kile

I'm using kile for creating my .tex files. I have a problem with the special characters (accented letters, arrows, greek letters). I try to use the shortcuts in the left, but when I click on the letters, nothing happens. Normally when you put the mouse over the symbols it shows the respective command as well, but this is not showing neither. Any idea?

Comment: On the off chance that you drop by the site: If my answer solved the problem for you, please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

(I assume you're referring to the symbol pane.) According to [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kile/forums/forum/292014/topic/4517306) on the forum of Kile's SourceForge page, there seemed to be a problem with dependencies in beta 4 of Kile 2.1, which caused this problem. It was fixed in beta 5, which can be installed from [source](http://kile.sourceforge.net/download.php), or from Debian packages compiled by Philip Muškovac:
[32-bit](https://launchpad.net/~yofel/+archive/backports/+build/2489577)/[64-bit](https://launchpad.net/~yofel/+archive/backports/+build/2489576).

This fixed the the issue for me as well.